# Clifford multiplication formula for $d\beta$ where $\beta$ is a $3$-form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spin-geometry, clifford-algebras, spinor

Say $X$ be a $6$-dimensional compact Riemannian manifold which admits a $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$ structure. Now I want to have a Clifford multiplication formula by $d\beta$ in terms of $\beta$ where $\beta$ is a real $3$-form on $X$. We know that w.r.t local coframes say $e_i,$ we have $d\beta=\sum e_i\wedge \nabla_i\beta$. If $\gamma(\theta)$ denotes the Clifford action by a form $\theta$, can we say somrthing about $\gamma(e_i\wedge \nabla_i\beta)?$ Is it equal to $\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma(e_i)\gamma(\nabla_i\beta)-\gamma(\nabla_i\beta)\gamma(e_i)\}?$

Comment: For a general vector field $X$ with dual one-form $\eta = \langle X,-\rangle$ we have $[\gamma(\eta),\gamma(\omega)] = -2\gamma(\iota_X\omega)$ (it is true for $\omega$ a $1$-form by definition of the Clifford algebra, and both sides are derivations in $\omega$), where the brackets denote the supercommutator. Then an easy induction shows $\gamma(\eta\wedge \omega) = \gamma(\eta)\gamma(\omega) - \frac{1}{2}\gamma(\iota_X\omega) = (-1)^{|\omega|}(\gamma(\omega)\gamma(\eta)+ \frac{1}{2}\gamma(\iota_X\omega)$. So the formula seems to be correct if you replace the minus sign by $(-1)^{|\omega|+1}$.

Comment: @BertramArnold, hence your comment suggests that for a three form $\beta$, it should be plus instead of minus. Can we recognize the object $\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma(e_i)\gamma(\nabla_i\beta)-\gamma(\nabla_i\beta)\gamma(e_i)\}?$

Comment: I think this is Clifford multiplication with the codifferential $\gamma(\delta \beta)$, up to signs and constants (use the formula I gave to identify it with $\gamma(\iota_{e_i}\nabla_i\beta)$).

Comment: @BertramArnold Thanks a lot, I will check this. Can you please give me a reference where the identities you mentioned are discussed?

Comment: The identities are an easy consequence of the explicit formula for the Clifford multiplication on the exterior algebra, cf https://mathoverflow.net/a/299655/35687. I'd be surprised if this wasn't in the classical defences Spin Geometry by Lawson.and Michelson or Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators by Berline,Getzler, and Vergne.